# unable to reference com.facebook.widget.LoginButton

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am working on an android app which uses the Facebook SDK (using the latest version, 3.6). This is my first time working with the SDK and trying to get up the simple login page work based on the example code available in the samples (scrumptious). I am unable to resolve the LoginButton in my xml layout. It is unable to reference com.facebook.widget.LoginButton. I tried copying the class file LoginButton source into my own class named FBLoginButton and then edited the layout file to look like this:

```
        <!-- <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton -->
        <!--<com.facebook.scrumptious.LoginButton  -->

        <com.example.myproject.FBLoginButton 
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

While my class FBLoginButton is free of errors in itself, I get the error:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.example.insultdroid.FBLoginButton (Open Class, Show Error Log)
```

I have already spent endless hours trying to get the LoginButton to work but to no success. Rebuilding, cleaning, restarting eclipse; I have done it all! Can someone please help me!

Adding a snapshot that shows that LoginButton class is available in the facebooksdk.jar which I have added to the dependencies.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The project you're working on... **have you imported the Facebook SDK and added the library to your current project?** (right click > Project > Android > Add... button in library section). Or check your Java build path -> Order and Export and make sure the facebook library is checked.

If you have, then it should work..., if you haven't, add the library and it should work.

Also, make sure under Android dependencies > facebooksdk.jar, that you see com.facebook.widget.LoginButton.

If it's still not working, try deleting the facebook library, re-adding it, close and restart Eclipse.

Comment: Yes I have imported the Facebook SDK and it and all the samples work just fine. However, this piece of code doesn't work when I am trying to set up the Login page for my app based on the same code that's given in the samples. I even tried re-adding the SK and restarting eclipse.

Comment: How do I add the facebooksdk.jar to my dependencies?

Comment: I did manage to add the facebooksdk.jar to my referenced libraries and I can see the LoginButton class in the list. But the error's still very much there. I am adding a snapshot just to clarify.

Comment: Have you checked the box next to referenced libraries when you go to properties > build path > order and export? Do all the other facebook classes work? if so, try redownload.

Comment: Darth, I am also still having this issue. Kindly advice how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure from where you got this component from... because the login button component starts with

```
<com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        .... />
```

just change the component name to it, it should work.
give me a feedback otherwise, happy programming

Comment: I know it's <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton.../>. I already tried working with it but it was throwing the error. Later I copied the class LoginButton to my project folder and renamed it to FBLoginButton which I have tried accessing through my project's namespace (com.example.myproject), based on another answer given somewhere else to a related question. This didn't work either!

Answer (score 0):

see that you have added the facebook SDK from properties->Android->Add library project and not in the build path.

This should solve the problem.