# Rendering Issues on Android Activity

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I've a sample Login activity like below. But Why am I getting the Rendering issues?
[image: Preview]

When I try to refresh the screen, there is a layover like below.
[image: Preview]

How can I fix this?

Here is my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<TextView android:text="Login With Facebook"

    android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#494949"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070890/unable-to-reference-com-facebook-widget-loginbutton  (If not, tell us that you've already done all the things in this question, and explain that here too)

Comment: Try to build your project. Does the problem persist? It's because that custom button, this happened to me a lot of times. Sometimes I just close it and ignore it.

Comment: @Baronz: I've already added my facebook sdk to my gradle build. That doesn't resolve my issue

Comment: You have to build the app in order for the Facebook views to be loaded, adding to the Gradle build just says you want to download the dependencies

Comment: @cricket_007 : Tried it. Doesn't work!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio 1.1.0 Facebook SDK Login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268738/android-studio-1-1-0-facebook-sdk-login)